# 1 html object - different functionalities (one-click and double-click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have with **jquery** a function, if i click on a html box, i get a small infobox, but my question is, can i have two different functionalities, if i click on the box,i get the small infobox, but if i do a **doubleclick**, then i should go to a other page? My code is so written:

```
<div onclick="getInofbox(id)"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
```

On click i get only small box with content, i can't found any doubleclick option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dblclick()` jquery event.

```
$('div').dblclick(function () {
    alert('Double click');
});
```

But according to jQuery API documentation it is not advisable to use click and dblclick event handlers to the same HTML element. You can refer API documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/).

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/EFZ66/)

Answer for your this question: "**I have leave now this solution, and open only first infobox with link, it is possible, if i click on one element and get the infobox, then if i click on other box, after click should be the first box closed?**"

You can register click for both link and when opening second infobox simply close the first infobox.

You check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/ZwPFU/1/), in this I have used jQuery UI dialog (which is not modal dialog), and closing first dialog on click of second one.

Comment: I have leave now this solution, and open only first infobox with link, it is possible, if i click on one element and get the infobox, then if i click on other box, after click should be the first box closed?

Answer (score 1):

To have a click and a double click event on a same element, use a timeout :

```
var timeout, doubleClick = false;

$('p').click(function() {
   timeout = setTimeout(simpleClick, 500); 
});

$('p').dblclick(function() {
    doubleClick = true;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    alert('Double click');
});

function simpleClick() {
    if(!doubleClick) {
        alert('Simple click');
    }
    doubleClick = false;
}
```

Here, you have a 0.5 second timeout. If it detects only a simple click, it calls the function for the simple click. Else, it clears the timeout and goes to the double click function.

[An exemple on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Q93q5/)